# Why does this markdown not render as a list?

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

If one looks at the source text for this question:

[Ceylon Run Configuration: can't find project](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51050829/1)

a list can be seen towards the bottom. However, this list is not rendered as a list, in spite of being formatted according to [the Markdown syntax for a list](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: It's odd that the explanation for this is missing in the documentation, it's a basic part of Markdown formatting.

Comment: So, apparently the question now been altered? Because this question makes no sense, since it is now rendered as a list.

Comment: I haven't altered anything

Comment: Someone else edited the post, but that's alright. Especially since I've got the syntax you used in my answer. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Add an extra blank line before your list.

You have your list and the previous line like this:

```
Worth noting:
 - My Workspace folder is `C:\Users\Jon\Aukitekt`
 - My project folder is `C:\Users\Jon\Aukitekt\milling`
 - Eclipse Oxygen version: `Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), Build id: 20180405-1200`
```

Which gives you this:

> Worth noting:
>    - My Workspace folder is `C:\Users\Jon\Aukitekt`
>    - My project folder is `C:\Users\Jon\Aukitekt\milling`
>    - Eclipse Oxygen version: `Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), Build id: 20180405-1200`

Format it instead like this:

```
Worth noting:

 - My Workspace folder is `C:\Users\Jon\Aukitekt`
 - My project folder is `C:\Users\Jon\Aukitekt\milling`
 - Eclipse Oxygen version: `Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), Build id: 20180405-1200`
```

And you'll get:

> Worth noting:
>
> - My Workspace folder is `C:\Users\Jon\Aukitekt`
> - My project folder is `C:\Users\Jon\Aukitekt\milling`
> - Eclipse Oxygen version: `Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), Build id: 20180405-1200`

Code blocks and lists need a blank line before them in order to format properly. Unfortunately, this is not listed in the help page for either code blocks or lists.